# Requests per second on a asp.net website benchmarking

Tags: asp.net, apache, iis, benchmarking

I have a question regarding the "Number of Requests per second" for a web site. I started Apache bench mark AB recently to load/stress test and the results aren't encouraging.

It shows 25 requests per second.
This is a asp.net web site hosted on IIS 7.5. I enabled http compression, Gzip, output caching added for .aspx and .html (kernel and user enabled).

here are the results from running a ab command like this 
**ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://localhost/Web1/Test.aspx 

Requests Per Second: 90.02[#sec(mean)]

Time per request: 11.54(ms) --> this number is good i am assuming**

More info on the Test.aspx is a simple html page with bootstrap css and the data is pulled using ajax.

i wrote another html page with the exact same html as the aspx and this html also uses AJAX filling the data(the same function being called on both the aspx and html).

When the tests were run against the html

**ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://localhost/Web1/Test.html

Requests Per Second: 1569.86[#sec(mean)]

Time per request: 0.637 (ms) --> pretty good**

If you can notice the difference between the html and aspx html is super fast as it only takes 0.637 comapared to 11.54 for aspx i.e 20x faster

Moving the same files to the production and running the tests shows the following.

--ASPX test--
**ab -n 1000 -c 100 -k http: //prod.server/Web1/Test.aspx

Requests Per Second: 20.98[#sec(mean)]

Time per request: 47.74 (ms) -->Ok but not  good** 
Note: -k is added but still i get 200 odd failures

**ab -n 1000 -c 100 http ://prod.server/Web1/Test.html

Requests Per Second: 20.91[#sec(mean)]

Time per request: 47.83 (ms) -->Ok but not  good** 
Note: -k is added but still i get 200 odd failures

As you can see on the prod. server the results are pretty discouraging.

- only 20.91 requests per second
- the html and ASPX both have the same response time

My question is i know that the localhost performs better but why the discrepancy between the html and aspx locally where as they perform the same on the production server.

Does this mean that the production Server IIS or the network on the server is slow?

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Is your web-application in Debug mode in web.config? Did you build your DLLs in Release mode? How many HttpHandlers and HttpModules are being invoked on each request? How busy is the sever's HDD? How does your production server's specs compare to your local machine? There's too many things to consider here.

Comment: The app is on the release mode. Even though i have HttpHandlers this particular page only makes one ajax call and updates the content. The server is much more powerful than my dev machine.Dev machine has 6gb ram, windows 7, 64 bit os where as my production server has 8gb running only IIS and it has windows 2008.

Comment: I did one more test for a small image(6kb) and the results are as below   localhost: 6621 requests per second   production server 20.98 requests per second. not sure why my server isn't hitting anything more than 30,40 requests per second.

Comment: @Bobby, it could be a network limitation from your ISP?

Comment: @AlexisWilke I will check with the server guys to see if they have any insight to this.

Comment: Sorry been busy with stuff but after talking to the ip guys the issue had been with a combination of the firewall and reverse proxy setup that caused these issues. Thanks @AlexisWilke